# Extracting frequency with custom tables for multi-response questions in SPSS

Tags: response, frequency, spss, frequency-distribution

I have the following the answers to a multi-response question in a sav file

```
p85_1 |p85_2 |p85_3
------------------- 
 1    | 1    | 0    
 1    | 0    | 0    
 0    | 1    | 0    
 1    | 1    | 1    
 1    | 1    | 0
```

I need to retrieve the frequency(-distribution) but using/through custom tables and SPSS syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this as a multiple response set (Analyze > Tables > Multiple Response Sets) and then drag that set onto the Custom Tables canvas.